# React renders component many times when fetching data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I'm using `fetch` api so my goal is to fire a `POST` request and then store the result received from this call in a state. This is the code that  I use:

```
interface IPreviewFile {
file: IFile;
}

export default function PreviewFileModal({ file }: IPreviewFile) {
  const source = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.source);
  const project = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.project);

  const data = {
    fileName: file.path,
    accountName: source.Name,
    bucket: source.bucket,
    id: source.id
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      fetch(`${API_URL}/api/project/${project.id}/filepreview`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
    ])
      .then(async ([aa]) => {
        const a = await aa.json();
        return [a];
      })
      .then((responseText) => {
        setStringArray(readString(responseText[0].value).data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [project.id, data]);

  console.log(stringArray);
  return (
    <>
      <div></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The `console.log(stringArray);` prints in the console all the time after delay of 2-3 seconds. As you can see, I use `Promise` in order to avoid this but for some reason it still happens. Any ideas what causes the re-rendering all the time and how to fix it?

Comment: `fetch` return a Promise so you don't need to use `Promise.all` since you are sending a single request. We need to know what `setStringArray` and `readString` do to understand if they mutate the redux state somehow causing the component to rerender

Comment: `readString` parses a csv string (https://react-papaparse.js.org/docs) while `setStringArray` sets this parsed string into the `stringArray` state.

Comment: [project.id, data] - dependency for useEffect uses the local variable 'data'. This will reinitialize on every render which causes render again.

Comment: How can I overcome this, send this object from the outside? @Boopesh

Comment: @anthino12 - if you want to fetch the data only when project.id changes then move the variable declaration (i.e const data = ) inside the useEffect and remove it from dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried changing the code a bit to avoid re-rendering the component due to the data variable added as a dependency to useEffect. I don't see any reference to stringArray, so i've added it as a state variable.

```js
export default function PreviewFileModal({ file }: IPreviewFile) {
  const source = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.source);
  const project = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.project);
  const [stringArray, setStringArray] = useState("");

   useEffect(() => {
     
    fetch(`${API_URL}/api/project/${project.id}/filepreview`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        fileName: file.path,
        accountName: source.Name,
        bucket: source.bucket,
        id: source.id
      })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
      result && setStringArray(readString(result.value).data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }, [project.id]);

  console.log(stringArray);
  return (
    <>
      <div></div>
    </>
  );
}
```